# Text exporting Techniques at client side

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I will have a table with generated data like below

```
a  : "Yes"
b  : "No"
```

And there is a button to export the above data, Actually the above data is coming from localStorage element. I want to export it to a text file. As of now I am just opening the data in new document using document.open method to save the html page. I don't think this is an efficient method. Please help me on this. I just want to write some data to a text file and then ask user to save or download. As this is completely client side application and do noy have any server support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the new download attribute.....

```
<script>
var sampletext ="this is an example\nPretty boring aye?";
var a = document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement("a")
    );
a.download = "export.txt";
a.href = "data:text/plain;base64," + btoa(sampletext);
a.innerHTML = "download example text";

</script>
```

Comment: If anyone having issues with the line break, use `\r\n`